# Plotting parallel coordinates with confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Is there an R package allowing to plot parallel coordinates with confidence intervals? Like the example below.

Or what would be the easiest alternative? Making multiple ggplots and printing them side by side with ggarrange or patchwork?

[image]

**Generated data**

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

#make new data
df = tibble(
  factor= c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"),
  var1 = rnorm(15, 50, 20),
  var2 = rnorm(15, 10, 4),
  var3 = rnorm(15, 2, 1))

#add confidence intervals
df = df %>% mutate(
  var1_lower = var1 - runif(1, 5, 15),
  var1_upper = var1 + runif(1, 5, 15),
  var2_lower = var2 - runif(1, 0.5, 2.2),
  var2_upper = var2 +  runif(1, 0.5, 2.2),
  var3_lower = var3 - runif(1, 0.1, 0.6),
  var3_upper = var3 + runif(1, 0.1, 0.6))

#reorder columns
df = df[c("factor", "var1", "var1_lower", "var1_upper", "var2", "var2_lower", "var2_upper", "var3", "var3_lower", "var3_upper")]
```

[image]

Comment: `ggparci` library might be useful for you. https://github.com/talgalili/ggparci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two libraries that let you plot parallel coordinate charts.

1. GGally
2. MASS
3. ggparci

I believe ggparci would be best fit for you question. As it allows you to plot confidence interval with the data. I have given the link to the library documentation in the comment above.

But, I am mentioning rest two for the benefit of everyone.

In GGally library you can use

```
ggparcoord(df, columns=1:10, groupColum = 5)
```

GGally has scale option for further processing of the plot.

I plotted df without any processing and it looks like :
[image]

And in MASS library there is a function called `parcoord()`

Example use:

```
# MASS library
library(MASS)

# Color
color <- colors()[as.numeric(iris$Species)*11]

# Plot
parcoord(iris[,c(1:4)] , col= color)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a possibility to show confidence intervals (var1_lower, var1_upper) vertically on var1 axis? Something like the figure on the original post. Or just like vertical lines (upper-lower CI).

Comment: I am sorry I tried plotting confidence interval using your data in ggparci but its not giving desired results. I am able to plot a graph similar to what's given above but not the confidence interval. If you want, I will withdraw my answer.